# package productQuantity doesnt exist

Tags: java, database

```
int minusQ = Integer.parseInt(new productQuantity.getBalance()) - Integer.parseInt(quant.getText());
```

It said package productQuantity doesn't exist. how can i rid this error. please need help.

Comment: Do you have a variable in scope called `productQuantity`? If so, remove the `new `. If not, what are you trying to refer to?

Comment: ahhm productQuantity is in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Delete "new" because I suggest that "productQuantity" is an existing variable. If I am wrong why is your class starting with lower letter ?

```
int minusQ = Integer.parseInt(productQuantity.getBalance()) - Integer.parseInt(quant.getText());
```

OR

```
int minusQ = Integer.parseInt(new ProductQuantity().getBalance()) - Integer.parseInt(quant.getText());
```